# Counting entries using a sub-query in SQL

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

| commercial | clicks |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 0 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 0 |

The table described above (the name of the table is a table) has 2 columns. The `commercial` column shows the ads shown to the user (the chronological order is irrelevant). The `clicks` column shows whether a user who saw the link clicked on it or not (0 - did not click, 1 - clicked).

I need to make a SQL query for how many advertisements there are upon clicking one, two clicks, three clicks, etc. (so for every number of clicks in the table), using a sub-query.

Thank you.

```sql
SELECT  commercial, SUM(click)
FROM     table
GROUP BY commercial 
ORDER BY commercial ASC
```

| commercial | clicks |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 0 |
| 9 | 2 |
| 10 | 0 |

I made this so far but then i get stuck on how to make a sub-query to calculate how many commercials are clicked once or 2 times.
My expected result is:

| clicks | commercial |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1,4,5,8,10 |
| 1 | 3,6 |
| 2 | 2,7,9 |
| 3 |  |

I'm also wondering if i could get this result

| commercial | clicks |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 0 |
| 9 | 2 |
| 10 | 0 |

Without using the SUM and GROUP BY function, please let me know if thats possible.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS.

Comment: ... as information hovering the `sql` tag says to do.

Comment: How do you tag dbms? i think i did it

Comment: Oh i see, so if im using BigQuery for my data, which tag is the correct one to use?

Comment: No, unluckily you can't avoid summing your clicks values.

Comment: "Without using the SUM and GROUP BY function" Never make such nonsense restrictions. Think about the query which can cover your use cases and produce the correct result. Then verify if the result is correct and the performance is good. If so, the query is fine. Not using SUM or not using GROUP BY has no advantage.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute a further aggregation and use BigQuery [`STRING_AGG`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#string_agg) for string aggregation.

```
SELECT num_clicks, 
       STRING_AGG(CAST(commercial AS STRING)) AS commercials
FROM (SELECT  commercial, 
              SUM(clicks) AS num_clicks
      FROM     tab
      GROUP BY commercial) clicks_per_commercial 
GROUP BY num_clicks
```

"*Without using the SUM and GROUP BY function, please let me know if thats possible.*": no, you can't bypass the summing aggregation step.

Comment: Thank you!
i also wanted to ask what is the most simple way you could get that result or did i already do the most bare bones you could get it?

Comment: The idea is that we're attempting to aggregate on the output of an aggregation, if we don't compute the intermediate step, we can't apply the last step. You really can't avoid a subquery in this situation.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad, i was refering to the first query i made
SELECT  commercial, SUM(click)
FROM     table
GROUP BY commercial 
ORDER BY commercial ASC
if there's a simper way to write this.

Comment: Aggregating with `SUM` + `GROUP BY` is the best way you can accomplish to that task.

Comment: Is there a way to use SELECT COUNT and ORDER BY to get the same result?

Comment: In the inner query you can do count with conditional aggregation by substituting `SUM(clicks)` with `COUNT(CASE WHEN clicks = 1 THEN 1 END)` but it's not worth it. Any other solution is likely to be less performant than this one (or not working).

Comment: I tried using the query you posted for an answer and i get this error "No matching signature for aggregate function STRING_AGG for argument types: INT64. Supported signatures: STRING_AGG(STRING); STRING_AGG(STRING, STRING); STRING_AGG(BYTES); STRING_AGG(BYTES, BYTES) at [2:8]"

Comment: Try with a cast then.

Comment: Can you explain me what CAST does? i never worked with it before.
i checked it and it does work now!

Comment: Cast converts into to string. Check the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select clicks, string_agg(commercial::varchar,',' order by commercial asc) as commercials
 from table 
group by clicks 
order by clicks asc;
```

Comment: Is there a different solution that doesnt uses the string_agg function?, i need to solve it using a sub query.

Comment: I don't think so